# Disable RDL Sandboxing SSRS with Dynamics

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I believe to be able to use the "custom code" feature in SSRS, I need to disable RDL Sandboxing.  I want this, as I need to run custom coded reports on the on-premise version of MS Dynamics CRM 2011...

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210591(v=sql.105).aspx

Extract:

As a result, certain features might not be available in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online. For example, custom code in your report definition will not work. For more information, see "Enabling and Disabling RDL Sandboxing".

Despite reading the link, there doesn't seem to be ANY instructions on howto actually disable this feature, can anyone advise that has experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is not clear inside the msdn page? I see all the steps inside

Comment: I can't find instructions howto disable it.

Comment: what about this part: "This topic describes each element in the <RDLSandboxing> element in the RSReportServer.Config file. For more information about how to modify this file, see How to: Modify a Reporting Services Configuration File."

Comment: Hmmmm.... Perhaps based on this, removing the <RDLSandboxing> element is the solution?

Comment: Didn't find an answer for this, but was able to connect to an instance of the db and check custom code was indeed working.  It would be good to have an answer though.